# connecting managed event source to an unmanaged event sink

Tags: c#, .net, events, com, interop

I'm trying to write a managed library in C# that will act as an event source for an existing C++ event sink. The problem I'm having is that when the unmanaged app calls AtlAdvise to get the connection point map for my library it is getting the error "0x80040200" (CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION) - There are a couple of MSDN articles about that error that are related to unmanaged <--> unmanaged communication and an invalid connection point map in the COM server, but nothing about a managed COM server.

I've loaded up the idl from an unmanaged C++ server that works and got a list of the events that are exposed and then created those same events in my code by doing the following:

Created dll that contains the interfaces I have to implement

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch), Guid("xxxxxx")]
public interface IMyInterface 
{
    ...
    methods here
    ...
```

Created dll that has the class that implements the 3 required interfaces

```
[Guid("xxxxxxx2")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyInterface), typeof(IMyOtherInterface), typeof(IMyThirdInterface))]
public class DeviceTranslator : IDisposable, IMyInterface, IMyOtherInterface, IMyThirdInterface
{
```

created delegates in the namespace of the managed interface

```
namespace myNS.Interfaces
{
    public delegate void DistributeMessage([In] ref OLDMESSAGE Message);
```

and created events in the actual IMyInterface

```
event DistributeMessage myDistributeMessage;
```

in my class I implemented the event:
public event DistributeMessage myDistributeMessage;

I can place a breakpoint in my constructor, see that the dll gets loaded properly, but when this piece of unmanaged code is called I get the error referenced above: (pDistributeSink is a CEventSink cast to an IUnknown*, and The GUID for IID_IDistributeEvent is the same GUID as IMyInterface)

```
hr = AtlAdvise(m_pUnknown, pDistributeSink, IID_IDistributeEvent, &m_dwConnectionPointCookie);
```

At this point I'm totally scratching my head and don't understand what else AtlAdvise needs to get its connection point map back from the CLR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I waited 5 days, spinning my wheels every day while unable to figure this out before throwing it up here, and now an hour later I figured it out...go figure.

Here's what I had to do (many thanks to [codeproject](http://69.10.233.10/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx#NetEvents))

I was inheriting from the outgoing event interface (IMyInterface) AND defining it within my ClassInterface attribute. I also had created the delegates within the namespace IMyInterface is in, not the namespace the DeviceTranslator class is in.

It turns out that I needed to:

- ONLY define this in the
  ClassInterface attribute and then not
  override the methods in that
  interface.
- Create delegates within my class
  library namespace that match the
  method signatures of IMyInterface
  exactly (which match the COM event
  sink client methods)
- create events within the class
  DeviceTranslator that are named
  exactly the same as the IMyInterface
  methods

It is explained very well in the link i posted above and was the first place that got it to truly sink in how everything is really operating and what has to be created where.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the correct codeproject link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx#NetEvents

Comment: So there is exactly one example on the web on how to do this?  Where else is this thing documented?  Or do I have to go dig in my local library for one of those 1000 page books with the big "COM" in the title?

Comment: @HaiPhan it's been a while since I had to dive into this (last time was probably around 6 years ago when I made this answer), but I remember the documentation on msdn and on the web in general being scarce. I doubt it have gotten any better, especially if it relates to COM as it's a pretty old technology by now. But if you find any good pieces using your google-fu I'm sure you will help someone if you post the link(s) here :)